# Java mail sender name masking

Tags: java, email

When I use like below to set friendly from name,

```
 // Set From: header field of the header.
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromemail,"Sender name","UTF8"));
```

I am not getting the sender name.

If the domain of from & to are same, then the actual sender name getting resolved from mail directory and appeared in email.

But if the sender domain and receiver domain are different, then the sender name getting displayed.

How to mask automatic resolving of sender name from mail directory and display only what I passed in as in code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be very careful when using a setfrom address that doesnt match the smtp server you are sending from - if the sending smtp server uses authentication then usually it sets the from name as the authenticated address and then sets the replyto as the fromemail address.  Can you enlighten use on how you are testing the behaviour you mention?  Ie what is your test procedure and environment.

Comment: Hi Narrim, i am sending from my SMTP server which does not require authentication. Without authentication, means without specifying username & password i am sending. I am using default 25 port of my smtp server.

Comment: There are more implications to it. If you send a mail from a@b.com via an SMTP server which is not an MX for b.com and/or isn't mentioned in an SPF record for b.com, the spam score for the mail rises, especially if the SMTP server identifies itself as MX for d.com. The question is, where does the resolving take place. It might well be that the SMTP server rewrites the address. Put plainly: there is nothing you could do about that save for reconfiguring the SMTPd in question.

Answer (score 1):

Mailbox Name resolution via a the mail protocol can occur at a number of different stages
1. It can be specified in the message.
or 
2. It can be retrieved by the receivers mail program / mail host

For example 
If I send a mail like so
From: Narimm@stackexchange 
To: someguy@someplace
Subject: Boring Stuff
Content: Stuff noone really cares about

If "someguy" had never received mail from me before he would simply have the message titled from my email address.
If I added on the From Line "Smart Guy" then Some guys would actually see my Name as Smart Guy, that is unless he has added my email address to his mail address book differently ...in which case the program would likely display it as From: "Dumb Guy".

Additionally it can be confused by the concept of alias where the "sender" is different to the "FROM" address

I guess what I am saying is that the problem you are seeing is not really a issue with java sendmail as it is an issue with the mail protocol and the programs that inteprete it.  My advice is take a look at the source code of the email recieved from your mailserver (the reciever).
You should implicitly declare the name ie From: "sarada@server.com" BUT you cannot control what a mail client will do - it is one of the inherently unreliable things about communicating on the internet...using Open protocols.  Interpretation is part of the equation we all have to deal with.